# Delpi RAD Studio 10.2 project, compile and build in a single executable file

Tags: delphi, build, compilation, executable, rad

I am giving a shot Delphi with RAD Studio, and so far so good; I am doing a very dead simple application that has buttons, which launches other files (MSI, VBS)

When building (both in debug and release), the exe I want is there, but I have to put my MSI and VBS files into a resource folder. Which, works. But isnt the best convenient and or portable option.

So you all can see what I mean, here it is:
https://github.com/audricd/OffDog

You can run the exe standalone, but every button (that launches the MSI and VBS mentioned files) will throw the error "the file cannot be found", unless the folder "resources" is at the same folder level.

So, is it possible to have a build option that, somehow, puts everything together in a single EXE? I have seen a lot of these.. Loads of programs have a single setup.exe with nothing on the side to make it run. Then again I dont know if these are made in Delphi.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, include the external files as embedded resources, and unpack them when you need them. However, this just wastes disk space. Better usually to keep these other files separate and distribute them all.

Comment: Or you could take a more modern approach and make your app just a stub which downloads the files it needs over the internet. Especially if you need to choose a file based on user's system.

Comment: I agree with David's suggestion about adding this files into your executable resources. There are many examples of how to do this available online. But beware that unless your application is signed with a trusted certificate it might be quickly flagged as potentially harmful software since extracting scripts from executable and then running them is very common in all sorts of malware.

Comment: thank you all for your answers. it all makes sense. the idea of having the resources online is brilliant. Tiny packaging, and easy to update! Its brilliant, thank you very much!